# Spring, Hibernate and AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests: objects with multiple mappings to same underlying data cannot be found

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit

I have successfully created numerous database-related unit tests for a Spring 2.5.6/Hibernate 3.5.3 project using [AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests.html). One example, where a Device object is created and then verified that the same object is included in the list of all Device objects:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/UnitTests-context.xml" })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class DeviceDaoTests extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    @Test
    public void testGetDeviceList() {
        Device device = new Device();
        this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(device);

        Query myQuery = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Device");
        List<Device> allDevices = myQuery.list();
        assertTrue(allDevices.contains(device);
    }
}
```

This test works.

The Device class, which is mapped to a table named DEVICES:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DEVICES")
public class Device {

//properties omitted for brevity and readability

}
```

There is also a class named DeviceListItem, which is mapped to a database view named DEVICESLIST_VIEW containing parts of the DEVICES table (as well as other tables):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DEVICESLIST_VIEW")
public class DeviceListItem {

//properties omitted for brevity and readability

}
```

Now if I want to test that inserting a Device in the database results in a DeviceListItem with the same id being found from the list of all DeviceListItem  objects (similarily to the first test), there is a problem - the following test fails:

```
   @Test
   public void testGetDeviceListItemList() {
      Device device = new Device();
      this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(device);

      Query myQuery = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from DeviceListItem");
      List<DeviceListItem> allDeviceListItems = myQuery.list();
      assertTrue(allDeviceListItems.get(0).getId().equals(device.getId())
  }
```

All the mappings, DAO classes etc. work when running the application on the web server - only the aforementioned unit test fails. This is probably because a new object of type Device is saved, but the items read are of type DeviceListItem and Hibernate does not "know" that they both refer to the same underlying database table and becase the objects are not really saved to the database.

Is there a way to make this test work, i.e. to test the scenario where a Device object is written to the database and read from the database as a DeviceListItem object?

(Please note that there might by typos, style issues etc. in the code examples, as the examples are strongly simplified and are not necessarily copy/pasted from actually executed code)

Comment: Have you tried doing a flush or commit? Just a guess though.

Comment: I have tried both, but with the same result - presumably because extending AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests nothing is really written to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding annotation

```
@Rollback(false)
```

(see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/reference/testing.html) to the method

```
testGetDeviceListItemList
```

(see original question). However, this means also that the Spring Unit test context does not make an automatic rollback, so I have to ensure that the database state is returned to normal afterwards manually:

```
this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(device);
```

Complete method:

```
       @Rollback(false)
       @Test
       public void testGetDeviceListItemList() {
          Device device = new Device();
          this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(device);

          Query myQuery = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from DeviceListItem");
          List<DeviceListItem> allDeviceListItems = myQuery.list();
          assertTrue(allDeviceListItems.get(0).getId().equals(device.getId());

          this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(device);
      }
```